# Does this particular molecule (pyridine-I-pyridine) have a common name?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Here's a pic of the molecule:

[image]

I've been investigating this system to test a computational chem method, but I've realized I don't really know a name for this system. $I-pyr_2$? $py_2I$?

In my mind I call it "pip" for pyridine-I-pyridine, but I don't want to publish and look silly finding out this has a common non-systematic name later (ex: quinine, caffeine, etc).

I'm not worried about getting an IUPAC name exactly right, becuase nobody actually does that. But if there's a more common way of calling it, that's what I want.

Comment: You understand it would need to be cation?

Comment: Yes it's a cation, but the stability isn't relevant here. I'm using it to benchmark computational methods, not use in a lab experiment

Comment: Ok, more stable then I suspected: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bis(pyridine)iodonium(I)_tetrafluoroborate

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed I didn't find that wiki article previously!
However that seems to be a salt of this particular molecule, not the thing itself.

Comment: There are plenty of databases that can be searched for that compound. [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.21494302.html) and [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2734711) are only the top two choices. And then there is [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=bispyridine-iodine) ... Also you failed to specify a charge (or state whether it is neutral). You shouldn't worry about looking stupid when publishing, you should worry about looking stupid in the peer review process. If you're unable to name a molecule, it won't get published anyway.

Comment: Please also see our [guidelines on how to ask and answer nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3066/).